# Temperature weather color change

Tags: jquery, css, api, wunderground

I done for my jQuery weather from wundground, I just want make color for  temperature change auto higher or lower and this code I use but I don't know how use CSS inside jQuery.

```
function check(temp_c) {
      if (temp_c < 1 && temp_c > 10)
        return '';
      else if (temp_c > 11.25 && temp_c < 33.75) {
        return '';
      } else if (temp_c > 33.75 && temp_c < 56.25) {
        return '';
      } else if (temp_c > 56.25 && temp_c < 78.75) {
        return '';
      } else if (temp_c > 78.75 && temp_c < 101.25) {
        return '';
      } else if (temp_c > 101.25 && temp_c < 123.75) {
        return '';
      } else if (temp_c > 123.75 && temp_c < 146.25) {
        return '';
      } else if (temp_c > 146.25 && temp_c < 191.25) {
        return '';
      } else if (temp_c > 191.25 && temp_c < 213.75) {
        return '';
      } else if (temp_c > 213.75 && temp_c < 236.25) {
        return '';
      } else if (temp_c > 236.25 && temp_c < 258.75) {
        return '';
      } else if (temp_c > 258.75 && temp_c < 281.25) {
        return '';
      } else if (temp_c > 281.25 && temp_c < 303.75) {
        return '';
      } else if (temp_c > 303.75 && temp_c < 326.25) {
        return '';
      } else {
        return '';
      }
    }


var temp_c = data.current_observation.temp_c ;
var temperature = check(temp_c );
```

Comment: What I would do is use your function to return a class name which relates to the temperature then apply it to whatever html element you're using to display the result. Something like:

`$("#weather-element").addClass(temperature);`

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify your code by just checking the upper bound of the temperature and letting control pass through each condition to set the highest value. Something like this:

```
function check(temp) {
    temp = parseFloat(temp);
    var tempClass = 'gt326'; // default class for > 326        
    if (temp < 326.25) tempClass = 'lt326'; 
    if (temp < 303.75) tempClass = 'lt303';
    if (temp < 281.25) tempClass = 'lt281';
    // and so on...

    return tempClass;
}
```

From there you can set the returned class using the `addClass()` method:

```
var temp_c = data.current_observation.temp_c ;
var tempClass = check(temp_c);
$('#myElement').addClass(tempClass);
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/otwpg06g/)

Comment: there no change with color temperature weather

Comment: I don't understand what you mean?